# javascript check if child node is element or text node

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have problem with `childNodes` as below :

```
 <ol>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Coca Cola</li>
 </ol>
 //childNodes.length = 7
```

but

```
<ol><li> Coffee </li><li> Tea </li><li> Coca Cola </li></ol>
//childNodes.length = 3
```

It seems each `\n` or `textnode` is considered a `child` ,how can i remove these from `childNodes`?

Comment: You can use `nodeType`. Text Nodes will have `nodeType = 3`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/72Ya3/).

Comment: this may be useful ,i tried to detect `\n` but can't

Comment: @Harry - Your comment actually qualifies as an answer. Why not post it as one?

Comment: You may use [`children`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljudbhkn.php)

Comment: @Harry - Ok. But your answer is an accurate solution for the question title "javascript check if child node is element or text node"

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can check if a given child node is a text node or not using the `nodeType`. Text nodes will have the `nodeType` as `3`. We can either use the number or [the constant `Node.TEXT_NODE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) for checking.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0].childNodes; // using [0] as there is only one ol in the demo
  console.log('Print with text nodes');
  for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) { // will output all nodes with "undefined" for text nodes
    console.log(el[i].innerHTML);
  }
  console.log('Print without text nodes');
  for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) { // will output only non text nodes.
    if (el[i].nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE) // or if (el[i].nodeType !== 3)
      console.log(el[i].innerHTML);
  }
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hey good answer, you can also use the constant `Node.TEXT_NODE` instead of the meaningless `3`.

Comment: @A1rPun: Nice suggestion. Will update into the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Text nodes can also be checked for using `nodeName`

```
node.nodeName === '#text'
```

Answer (score -5):

try to use jquery children method
`$("#test").children().size()`

http://jsfiddle.net/72Ya3/2/

Comment: This trivial requirement does not need jQuery. The other answer is way more correct as well as informative.

Comment: This can be done with plain JavaScript: `element.nodeType === 3 // true when element is a text node`. See @Harry's answer, which should likely be the accepted one, and the [MDN article on nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).

Comment: Why downvoting though? jQuery is widely used and this answer may come in handy.