# Angular - Only allow text in ng-content

Tags: angular, transclusion

Is it possible to limit the contents between my ng-content tags to just text?  How can I do this?

I understand I can use a type-safe input parameter as an alternative, but I would still like to know if this is possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this vs just using an input property?

Comment: Personal preference mainly, I find it easier to use/read. I will use an input if necessary, but I am curious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  template: `
    <div #wrapper>
     <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class FooComponent {
  @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    var nodes = this.wrapper.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      if (nodes[i].nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE) // or if (nodes[i].nodeType != 3)
      throw 'Only text is supported as content
    }
  }
}
```

See also [javascript check if child node is element or text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971177/javascript-check-if-child-node-is-element-or-text-node)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I was hoping that it was directly supported, but it's helpful to see this approach.

Comment: I'm sure there currently isn't. Glad to hear this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive which get inner text and replace element content.

Example

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[text-content]'
})
export class TextContentDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(
      private el: ElementRef
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.extractTextContent()
  }

  private extractTextContent() {
    this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.el.nativeElement.innerText
  }

}
```

where you want to keep only the internal text:

```
<h1 text-content><ng-content select="dialog-header-title"></ng-content></h1>
```

output:

```
<h1 text-content>My Title</h1>
```